# iTextSharp : block element like div?

Tags: itext

today, i'm working with iTextSharp and I'm trying to create a PDF document with a specific structure. For that, I need to insert "blocks" (like a div in HTML) in my PDF document. This blocks have to have a border.

At the moment, i'm using PdfPTable element but I would like know if another block type exists. In my blocks, I will insert Paragraph elements, Table elements, ...

Thanx for your help

Comment: Yes, you're looking for `ColumnText`.

Comment: Thanx for your answer. But if I want a block with a 100% width, I think that ColumnText is not the best solution no ?

Comment: What is a block with 100% width? PDF is a Page Description Language. You define pages using a rectangle of which the coordinates are known in advance (as opposed to most HTML pages). If you want a column to take 100% of the width, why not define a column of which the width corresponds with the width of the page in the PDF document?

Comment: Yes you have right. But how set a border width and a border color to a ColumText ? I found any Border property :/

Comment: You know the dimensions, so it's easy to draw a rectangle using the `rectangle()` method.

Comment: I you're thinking like a web developer and are trying to avoid tables for structured content just because that's what we web developers do, I would think again. There are no tables in a PDF just as there are no paragraphs or words even. Those objects are just helpers provided by iText to solve certain problems. Tables are a great way to create multiple blocks of content that flow together, wrap as needed, have automatic rectangles that you can draw borders around, are nestable and can easily span pages, too. Unless you have a specific problem with tables I would stick with them.

Comment: Yes i'm trying to create my layout with tables now. But I have a problem : if the first cell of my table is longer than my page, a pagebreak is inserted before my table. How avoid this pagebreak please ?